# Passing variable to .NET dll in ColdFusion

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I built a very simple .dll in C# to call from a simple ColdFusion page. Everything works fine if I pass in literal values but as soon as I try and pass in a variable (`#rollYear#`) I get a message stating it can't find the method anymore.

The coldfusion page sets up my .dll like this:

```
<cfobject type="dotnet" name="getParcelData" 
        class="soapDLL.GetSecuredParcelByAPN"    
        assembly="{path}\soapdll.dll">
```

I then call it like this:

```
<cfset output = getParcelData.getData("46546504654","cy","#rollYear#")>
```

If I use the code above I get an error, *"The getData method was not found."*. If I replace the `#rollYear#`  variable with a value (2017 for instance) then it works fine. In my tests I've set the `#rollYear#` variable via the `CFSET` function before I call the .dll.

I've been banging my head on this all day. Has anyone had similar experience? The .dll is very simple. It just takes 3 variables and based on those sets up what SOAP service to call to pull back some data. For reasons that are too complicated to explain I can't do the SOAP call from within ColdFusion, it has to go through a .net dll.

Any help would be appreciated, I don't have much hair left. :)

Comment: With the working value, do you pass `..."cy","2017")>` or `..."cy",2017)>`? What data type does the 3rd argument expect? You might have to cast the ColdFusion variable using [`javaCast()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/javacast.html) to match the method signature of .NET's `getData`.

Comment: That was it, the javacast to a string fixed the problem. THANK YOU!

Comment: I nominate @Alex to post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you work with Java or .NET components, you need to pay extra attention when passing ColdFusion variables/values to those methods. If the data types to not match exactly, you will encounter an error message telling you that the method does not exist or does not match the method signature.

ColdFusion offers [`javaCast()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/javacast.html) to explicitly cast to the required data type. Cast your arguments accordingly and it should work out in most cases.

**Basic example:**
A method that expects an integer will throw an error when you pass `methodThatExpectsInt(123)`, because the `123` literal is internally stored as a string (or Double) by ColdFusion. By passing it via `methodThatExpectsInt( javaCast("int", 123) )`, the data type will be properly casted and match up.